# How does cin.peek() work in c++?

Tags: c++

when i use cin.peek() with a "char" data type it works perfectly fine but it does not work with "string" data type.
this works fine:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout<<"enter a word"<<endl;
  char a;
  cin>>a;
if(cin.peek()=='c'){
  cout<<"ha"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

if input is "dce" it prints "ha" but
 the code below doesnot do the same job:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout<<"enter a word"<<endl;
  string a;
  cin>>a;
if(cin.peek()=='c'){
  cout<<"ha"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

isn't the string data type more appropriate as we are storing words in "a" variable. can "char" data type be used to store words or only single letters?

Answer (score 3):

[cin.peek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/)
Returns the next character in the input sequence, without extracting it: The character is left as the next character to be extracted from the stream.

For your both codes the input is `dce`

In first code

```
char a;
cin>>a
```

It take only `d` from the input buffer and `ce` is still in it, So when you do `cin.peek()` it gets the next character from buffer that is `c`.
But for second code

```
string a;
cin>>a;
```

As the data-type is string it takes whole `dce` from input stream buffer and when you do `cin.peek()` it checks if there is anything in the stream but now there isn't.
Hence it returns `EOF`

> If there are no more characters to read in the input sequence, or if
>   any internal state flags is set, the function returns the end-of-file
>   value (EOF), and leaves the proper internal state flags set:

Comment: @user6321887 If this solved your question, please mark it as so it is helpful for others too